# GPO Templates Resource?

Tags: group-policy

I am in the process of designing the group policies for my organization, and I'm wondering if there is somewhere I can go to look at templates, to see how other people have set theirs up, and even download templates to work off of.

Comment: Could you narrow down, a bit, which specific areas you're interested in? Group Policy and Group Policy Preference Client Side Extensions offer myriad options.  Add in your own custom ADM/ADMX and you can do [almost] anything. It might be better to scope your configuration to your requirements, rather than just applying someone else's.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question and there's really no "right" answer, but you could take a look at Starter GPO's: http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/group-policy-related-changes-windows-server-2008-part1.html

Comment: It is really broad, I want to be able to see what kind of really cool stuff other people have done. Were doing a pretty standard deployment, so pretty basic GPO's work just fine, I just want to see the possibilities and maybe get some ideas.